# MySQL Server with high CPU and "kernel time" usage

Tags: mysql, mariadb, windows-server-2012-r2

I noticed that a mysql server is with CPU at 100%, and the "kernel time" (I'm not sure what it means) is unusually high, about 70%.

There are many connections on this server (around 400) and some active queries (about 40). Would that explain this behavior? Is there something wrong or this is expected?

[image: High kernel time]
[image: MySQL CPU usage]

**Edit:**

As suggested by a comment, I checked the 'handler_read%' variables:
`show global status like 'handler_read%'`. Here are the results:

```
Handler_read_first          248684
Handler_read_key            3081370400
Handler_read_last           83333
Handler_read_next           3520958058
Handler_read_prev           330
Handler_read_rnd            2210158755
Handler_read_rnd_deleted    60107588
Handler_read_rnd_next       929907565
```

The complete `show status` and `show variables` result is here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/98pnd1rzgfp4jtf/server_status.txt?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rh0m8np0mosx6tp/server_variables.txt?dl=0

Comment: Some more information would be helpful, e.g. the values of handler variables: SHOW variables LIKE 'Handler_read%'

Comment: are the tables you're using MyISAM? It does not use much caching in its own, just relies on filesystem caching, and thus does a lot more system calls (ReadFile/WriteFile), than Innodb. It is just a guess, based on high kernel time. For a thorough understanding you'd need some profiler that can output callstack(on Windows , you might want to use xperf from Windows PErformance Toolking (probably from current Windows SDK). Alternatively, you can also use performance schema - but I'm not very familiar with that myself to give a good advise.

Comment: Also, the status shows about 230 active threads, rather than 40 at the moment where the "show status" was taken. "show processlist" can shed some light into what queries are doing.

Comment: How much RAM?  Is Innodb turned off?

Comment: 64GB Ram on that box (in task manager). mysqld is using just 1.3GB of that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **high** values for **handler_read_rnd*** indicate  that your tables are not properly indexed or that your queries are not written to take advantage of the indexes you have.

Due to syscall overhead and context switches table scans use more CPU.

Before changing parameters or invest money in hardware, I would suggest to optimize your database:

- Activate the slow query log (additionally you might specify parameters log_queries_not_using_indexes and min_examined_row_limit) for a limited time (size of slow query log might grow very fast).
- Analyze the queries in query log with EXPLAIN or EXPLAIN EXTENDED
- If the problems occurs on a production server, replicate the content first to a test system

Comment: There were some queries using a view that was a join of 3 tables. Converting that to a real table already helped reducing the kernel time. The CPU is still high, though. We'll continue investigating. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Also, there were some tables that were not properly indexed, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

A number of settings are too high or too low...

- `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` are 16G -- This is disastrous!  Each connection might need one or more of these.  Lower it to 1% of RAM.
- There are a large number of `Com_show_fields` -- complain to the 3rd party vendor.
- Large number for `Created_tmp_disk_tables` -- this usually means poorly indexed or designed queries.
- `Select_scan` / `Com_select` = 77% -- Missing lots of indexes?
- `Threads_running` = 229 -- they are probably tripping over each other.
- `FLUSH STATUS` was run recently, so some STATUS values are not useful.
- `table_open_cache` is 256 -- There some indications that a bigger number would be good.  Try 1500.
- `key_buffer_size` is only 1% of RAM; raise it to 20%.

Still, ... High CPU means poor indexes and/or poorly designed queries.  Let's see some of them, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.